# How to optimize this program?

Tags: c++, string, loops, optimization, deque

I am attending a coding competitions in February and I'm looking at last years problem set. The task I am trying to do is this. As input i am given an integer N(maximum 10,000,000), and a string S of length N. The string consists of only the letters 'x', 'y' and 'z'.

These letter are all 'commands'. You start out with a word consisting of only the letter 'A'. If you get a command 'x' you will add an 'A' to the back of you word.

Command'y' will add a 'B' at the front of the word. And 'y' will flip the word. So an input of N = 3, and S = "xyz", will make the word be "AAB". x: add 'A' ,y: add 'B' and z: flip the entire word.
This entire thing has to be done in under 2 seconds, which seems to be a problem for me to achieve. 
I hope all that was understandable...

Well, the solution explanation said that a double-ended queue would be the most efficient way to do this, but it I can't get it any lower than a little more than 10 seconds execution time. Could someone please help me find a way to optimize this code.

```
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int num = 10000000;
    string commands = "";
    bool reversed = false;

    deque<char>word = { 'A' };

    // just for generating the input. The real program would not need this
    for (int i = 0; i < num / 5; i++) {
        commands += "xyzxy'";
    }


    //cin >> num >> commands;


    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

        if (commands.at(i) == 'x') { //If the command is 'x' add an A at the back
            if (!reversed)
                word.push_back('A');
            else // if it the word is reversed, reverse the command
                word.push_front('A');
        }

        else if (commands.at(i) == 'y') { //If the command is 'y', add a 'B' at the front
            if (!reversed)
                word.push_front('B');
            else // if it the word is reversed, reverse the command
                word.push_back('B');
        }
        else if (commands.at(i) == 'z') { // If the command is 'z' set the status to reversed/!reversed
            reversed = !reversed;
        }
    }

    if (reversed)
        reverse(word.begin(), word.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) { // print out the answer

        cout << word.at(i);
    }

    system("pause");

        return 0;
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: push_back or push_front must be slow. add two push_backs for 2 queues and then reverse one of them and concatenate them(if push_front is the slow one)

Comment: Looking at your example I would guess that the majority of time is spent generating the input and printing the results. If you measure how much time only the actual processing takes I would assume it is much less than 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do that.

Comment: The for loop that processes is what takes about 10 seconds. It takes about 3 seconds to generate the input. No idea about the printing, but that's a lot longer.

Comment: Have you try to replace `at(i)` by `[i]` ?

Comment: Yeah, didn't make a difference.

Comment: You may get rid of `if (!reversed)` with a function table. That change branch prediction to jump prediction...

Comment: Have you try `word.reserve(command.size())` ?

Comment: Have you run profiler to see where time is spend ?

Comment: Really stupid question. Have you built a release build or otherwise turned on any compiler optimization?

Comment: @user4581301 I am an idiot... thank you!

Comment: Recommend finding out what compiler and options the competition you are attending uses and practice against that. For example, I believe ACM used `g++` with `-g -O2 -std=gnu++14 -static` last year. If you know the target PC, os, and build system you can cheat like hell, writing code that screams on that particular system even if it crashes and burns everywhere else. Caveat: This generates awesomely poor real world solutions, but competitive programming is a very poor simulation of the real world programming environment.

Comment: Can you tell us which competition this is for?

Comment: Oh, it's just a high school thing in Norway. Norwegian IT Olympiad. This was problem number two of last years part two of the competition.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we expect that a server executes 10^6 commands per second.

Bearing in mind that N=10,000,000 and time limit is 2 seconds, O(n) complexity is required.

You can achieve that using the following technique:

Use a double linked list.

Use a boolean variable, for example flag, that gives true if result string starts at the front of linked list and false if the string starts at the back of the linked list.

For each character of input string push_back if given character is x, push_front if given character is y and change the value of flag.

When reading input finishes, print the string respectively to flag value.

Complexity: O(n)

Comment: Is the double linked list faster than the deque I'm currently using?

Comment: It's not the data structure that makes it faster. Is the fact, that you don't need to reverse. Reverse costs O(n^2). The technique I described costs O(n) because it avoids reverse

Comment: But i am only reversing one time in my code too. The only difference between this answer and my question is the use of a double linked list instead of a deque.

Comment: In my code, there is no need to reverse, not even once. You just iterate through the double linked list from the last element to the front one

Comment: Oh, okay thanks. It helps not having to reverse. But that only cuts down my time with about a second. I still need about 7 seconds shorter execution time.

Answer (score 0):

The trick has two parts.

1. Use `std::deque`, which is optimized for insertion at both ends of the container.
2. Do not flip the word for the 'z' input. Instead, keep track of how many times 'z' was read, and change the code that adds `A` and `B` so that if the number of times is odd, the character is added to the other end of the word.

At the conclusion of the input, flip the string just once, if the final count is odd.

The main trick is to avoid wasting time flipping the string over and over again. You only need to flip it at most once.

Comment: Perhaps the trick is: instead of adding a single character, each time, keep track of how many of the same character is consecutive. Similar to run-length encoding, and generate the final string on the final pass.

Answer (score 0):

Observation: push_back on vector is faster than both push_back and push_front on deque.

If you use two vectors (front and back) and treat the front as if it is reversed, then you can also eliminate all of the 'if (reverse)...' stuff by using push_back on the back vector for the x, push_back on the front vector for the y, and swapping the vectors when you hit a z.

Then when outputting the result, do a reverse iteration through the front vector and a forward iteration through the back vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto fileIn = std::ifstream{"flip.in"};
    int commandSize;
    std::string commands;
    fileIn >> commandSize >> commands;

    std::vector<char> wordFront;
    std::vector<char> wordBack;
    wordFront.push_back('A');

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (auto v : commands)
    {
        switch(v)
        {
            case 'x':
                wordBack.push_back('A');
                break;
            case 'y':
                wordFront.push_back('B');
                break;
            case 'z':
                std::swap(wordFront, wordBack);
                break;
        }
    }
    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = finish - start;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time (secs): " << elapsed.count() << std::endl;

    auto fileOut = std::ofstream{"flip.out"};

    std::for_each(crbegin(wordFront), crend(wordFront), [&fileOut](auto v){ fileOut << v; });
    std::for_each(cbegin(wordBack), cend(wordBack), [&fileOut](auto v){ fileOut << v; });
}
```

It didn't make a positive difference on my machine, but you could also reserve some space on the front and back vectors before you start building the word.

Comment: Thank you. This looks so much more elegant than my code. I have just started learning cpp. My language of choice is Java. So I see I have a lot to learn, I'm both languages really